# Need a program that continously listens to the Oracle DB and if any DML's are made it calls another program?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, wrapper

I have an Oracle DB with a lot of tables ... How can I write something which listens to the Oracle DB and if any changes are made to the DB, it calls another program which does some processing

1. It would be asnync
2. I just need to trigger a java program if there is any kind of DML happening .. I don`t want details about which table or what rows or new/old values ... 
   If there is a DML on any table in a DB call a java program that`s it

Comment: It would be great if you can explain why are you looking for something like this. Refer to [The XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/182862)

Comment: With your update, it sounds as if Oracle's (policy based) Fine Grained Auditing may meet your needs.

Comment: So I have a program which reads the updated values ... but I have to run it manually .. I want to trigger that automatically when a DML occurs in the DB .. so that it can do the processing

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/win.101/b10118/o4o00118.htm
OracleDB has some events. Just try to use them; For example, when the db is updated - And to call another java program:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(/*Here the argument*/);

Comment: I guess http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/dcn-otn-085625.html   JDBC DCN is another way .. but the constraint is that you have associate a query with every object which is not what I want... As I just want to call another program if any of the tables has any kind of change..

Answer (score 0):

I fear you're setting yourself up for failure here. I suggest a related, but slightly different course of action.

Rather than trigging your processing on every data change, consider instead having your processing run every X minutes/hours/whatever using something like [Cron](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html) or [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

If you're worried about having it run when no changes have been made, you can add triggers to your tables to update a "last updated" table and you can abort if no changes have been made since the last run.

This avoids the biggest concern you would have with an "on-update-processor", namely **what do you do if there's an update**, which triggers a process, and **while that process is running** another update happens. Do you trigger another process? What if they conflict? I think you'll find it better to allow there to be a slight delay between the update and the synchronization process.

Comment: How can I run a java program every 2 minutes, using multithreading ( I haven`t used it extensively before) and not CRON ... Bcoz my java program has a lot of dependencies and I don`t want to compile it using cmd ... I just want the program to run continuosly in eclipse itself using multithreading .. After I start it once

Comment: @gusc why to reinvent the wheel? I guess there must be a monitor for your Oracle database like [MyOra](http://myorasql.com/), or you can refer to [this Q/A](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7430/tools-to-monitor-oracle-database-performance-on-standard-edition)

Comment: @gusc If your program has a lot of dependencies, you shouldn't be using Eclipse - you should build an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) script or something similar. In any event, using [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/) operates inside the application, not outside. So your application would always run, and simply fire off a job within the application every 2 minutes (or however often you wanted).

Answer (score 0):

That's a pretty tall order for a question.

For starters, you are going to need a way to detect that a DML operation (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) has occurred.

For auditing on individual tables, we can use TRIGGERS.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [BEFORE|AFTER] [INSERT][UPDATE][DELETE] ... [FOR EACH ROW]
```

The normative action is to record information about the information (whatever is needed later) in an "audit log" table. You have to make a decision whether the operations you need to perform are synchronous (should happen before the DML completes) or whether those operations can be asynchronous (can happen anytime after the DML completes).

Normally, synchronous processing is done in PL/SQL, but Oracle does provide a mechanism for calling external procedures (EXTPROC), though you wouldn't want to do that from a TRIGGER.

Oracle also provides "fine grained auditing". The information gathered by FGA is not at a "row by row" level, like we can get with a FOR EACH ROW trigger.

So, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.

The next step is figuring out how you are going to get this information to your external process. Is that process going to periodically poll table (or set of tables), are you going to use AQ Advanced Queueing, or some other queue mechanism.